# Uniquely identify function definition node

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to uniquely identify function definition nodes in CDT AST?

```
void g() { ... }

void f() {
    g();
}
```

I need to store the function definition nodes for `f` and `g` in some structure and then, when I come to the function call node for `g`, I need to check if that node corresponds to the function definition node for `g`.

Right now I'm doing that by storing function's name.
The problem is that I cannot correctly handle the following case:

```
void f() {}

class F {
    void f() {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:

- Resolve the name to the function binding via `IASTName.resolveBinding()`
- The binding will be an instance of `ICPPFunction`, which extends `ICPPBinding`. (I'm assuming this is C++ code as you mention a `class`.)
- Use `ICPPBinding.getQualifiedName()` as the unique identifier for the function. In your example, the two functions would have different qualified names, `f` vs. `F::f`.

Comment: "In your example, the two functions would have different qualified names, f vs. F::f." What would happen with two `f`s in different anonymous namespaces?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Can you have two different anonymous namespaces in the same AST? Or are you talking about uniquely identifying entities across different ASTs in a project (which is a different problem statement)?

Comment: I assumed two `namespace { ... }` blocks in the same file create different anonymous namespaces, it looks like I was wrong.